# pass AJAX response to different divs in html through json encode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to send AJAX response in 2 different `<divs>` to display data. This is what i have tried. ANy suggestion please where am i doing wrong?

**script**

```
 $("document").ready(function(){
        $("#search_form").on("submit",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post("result.php?query="+encodeURIComponent($("#list_search").val()),function(data) {
                //$('.coupons').html(data);
                $('.coupons').html($('#inner1' , data).html());
                $('.coupons_im').html($('#inner2' , data).html());
            });
        });
```

**divs**

```
<div class="coupons"></div>
<div class="coupon_im"></div>
```

**php**

```
$res=$row['c_name'];
$res1=$row['c_desription'];
echo json_encode("<div id='inner1'> $res </div> <div id='inner2'>$res1</div>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `json_encode()` in `PHP` to and you have misspelled class in your AJAX `coupons_im` needs to be `coupon_im`

```
echo json_encode(['inner1' => "<div id='inner1'> $res </div>", 'inner2' => "<div id='inner2'>$res1</div>"]);
```

And Javascript

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#search_form").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("result.php?query=" + encodeURIComponent($("#list_search").val()), function (data) {
            var res = JSON.parse(data);
            $('.coupons').html(res.inner1);
            $('.coupon_im ').html(res.inner2);
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: @2by2 How it will know that `inner1` is a class or id in line `$('.coupons').html(res.inner1);`

Comment: no error!  But not displaying response in divs. I am not sure but i think when i type "off" in my search form. It should return 4 rows with following data. `c_description` and `c_name` in 2 divs mentioned above. Is it because i am trying to send multiple rows within 2 divs?

Comment: how do you get this values in your PHP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144782/discussion-between-tabia-and-2by2).

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to send an array from php, and then, from JS select the object you want.

#### PHP :

```
$res=$row['c_name'];
$res1=$row['c_desription'];
echo json_encode([
    "inner_1" => "<div id='inner1'> $res </div>",
    "inner_2" => "<div id='inner2'>$res1</div>"
]);
```

#### JS :

```
$.post(
    "result.php?query="+encodeURIComponent($("#list_search").val()),
    function(data) {
        $('.coupons').html(data.inner_1);
        $('.coupon_im').html(data.inner_2);
    },
    'json' // tell JS that the php response is json formated
);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I do not misunderstand you. The answer is:
   `$('.coupons').html(data);
    $('.coupons_im').html(data);`

Comment: i want to display `inner1` div  into `coupons` div and `inner2` div into `coupon_im` div.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this changes will helps you

```
     $("document").ready(function() {
            $("#search_form").on("submit", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.post("result.php?query=" + encodeURIComponent($("#list_search").val()), 

function (data) {

                    $('.coupons').html(data.inner1);
                    $('.coupon_im ').html(data.inner2);
                }, "json");
            });
        })
```

then in PHP

```
 $res=$row['c_name'];
$res1=$row['c_desription'];
$data['inner1'] = "<div id='inner1'>". $res." </div>";
$data['inner2'] = "<div id='inner1'>". $res1." </div>"
echo json_encode($data);
```